# How to convert 4 bytes array to float in java

Tags: java, char, type-conversion

I have a 4 bytes array which represent a float value. The bytes is read from network, for example, 3e 3f e3 a0. How can I convert it from byte[] to float in java?

Comment: Peters answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: Should it? Peter's answer requires constructing an object while Xavier's doesn't.

Answer (score 86):

In Java a `char` is 16-bit. If you mean you have a 4 `byte` values in little endian byte order which you need to convert to a `float` you can use `ByteBuffer`.

```
byte[] bytes = { }
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

Comment: Very useful class indeed.

Comment: There is also version with offset and length:  ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes,offset,length)

Comment: The order! That did it for me.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

`float foo = Float.intBitsToFloat( buffer[n] ^ buffer[n+1]<<8 ^ buffer[n+2]<<16 ^ buffer[n+3]<<24 );`

Comment: XOR?  Don't you mean OR?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.

```
// {64, 46, -128} = 15.28
byte[] bt = {64, 46, -128};
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).put(bt);
byteBuffer.position(0);
Double d = byteBuffer.getDouble(); // 15.28
```