# Converting byte array to float

Tags: java, android

I want to convert a 4-element byte array which I receive from socket connection to float. I searched on Google and tried several methods but couldn't help myself.

**UPDATE**
The proper way to convert byte array to float is using this code:

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getFloat();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469681/how-to-convert-4-bytes-array-to-float-in-java?rq=1

Comment: What are the methods you tried and how they didn't work?

Comment: I tried `float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(size).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();` but it doesn't return what I expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getFloat();
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa) , Use these methods:

```
float fromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
     return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getFloat();
}

float fromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
     return bytes[0] << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF)
}
```

Comment: You are casting int to float in the second method. Should use Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits).