# Send data over BLE with RFDuino

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, rfduino

I've attached sensor to RFDuino and want to send readings over BLE to Android app.

```
const int sensorPin = 2;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RFduinoBLE.begin();
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  float voltage= sensorValue * (3.3 / 1023.0);
  Serial.print("uv sensor = ");
  Serial.println(voltage);
  RFduinoBLE.sendFloat(voltage);
  delay(1000);
}
```

In console I see values like `0.2`. But in app it translates to something like `00-00-A4-41` It's described [here](http://forum.rfduino.com/index.php?topic=405.0) but I don't get what's the logic behind it. How do I properly convert the value sent from RFDuino?

Comment: This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469681/how-to-convert-4-bytes-array-to-float-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFduino sends floats in little endian. Your android app will receive it as 4 bytes and you will need to convert it to big endian by reversing the order of the bytes (and converting to float). There's several threads on the topic, eg. [Converting Little Endian to Big Endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842828/converting-little-endian-to-big-endian) and the one you used.

It should just be a quick read up on endianness and floating point format to understand the logic behind it. But basically, the 4 byte float has the bytes stored in reverse order of each other in little vs. big endian. When you reverse the 4 bytes in little endian then it becomes big endian and you're good to go for your situation.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format