# How to Properly Read Float Characteristic in Android Studio

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am using the ArduinoBLE library to create a service and characteristic:

```
BLEService angleService("1826");
BLEFloatCharacteristic pitchBLE("2A57", BLERead | BLENotify);
```

I add the services and characteristics and advertise my device:

```
  BLE.setLocalName("acsAssist");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(angleService);
  angleService.addCharacteristic(pitchBLE);
  BLE.addService(angleService);
  pitchBLE.writeValue(0);
  BLE.advertise();
```

I perform some calculations and then write my calculated value to the service:

```
 pitchBLE.writeValue(posiPitch);
```

`posiPitch` is a float value, like 1.96 for example. it can go from -90.00 to 90.00

I try to read this value from my Android app:

```
(characteristic.getFloatValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_SFLOAT,0))
```

I get crazy numbers such as `-1.10300006E9`.

How can I read my float value so that my android app value matches that of the arduino value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue. Instead of using getFloatValue(), I used getValue() which returns a byte array.

The reason for the weird numbers is that the byte order in which arduino stores data is different from that of java.

To change the order use byteBuffer:

```
byte[] b = characteristic.getValue();
float f = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getFloat();
```

This post helped me: [How to convert 4 bytes array to float in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469681/how-to-convert-4-bytes-array-to-float-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified the situation drastically by utilizing a string characteristic instead.

Although this is probably more resource intensive, it reduces the headache of having to parse through a byte array to convert the data into what I want.

My string characteristic is made with a custom UUID (to avoid Bluetooth GATT standard conflicts):

```
BLEStringCharacteristic pitchBLE("78c5307a-6715-4040-bd50-d64db33e2e9e", BLERead | BLENotify, 20);
```

After I advertise and perform calculations as shown in my original post, I simply write to my characteristic and pass in the value as a string:

```
pitchBLE.writeValue(String(posiPitch));
```

In my Android application, I simply get the characteristic's string value:

```
characteristic.getStringValue(0)
```

I hope this will help future developers like me who are struggling to find clearer resources on information such as this :)